# CMake target_link_libraries not preserving order

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, g++, clang++

I am using CMake 3.8.2 (shipped with JetBrains CLion) and linking several static libraries of a custom project.

As I am required to preserve static symbols (legacy), I am including my own program parts with `target_link_libraries(${TARGET} -Wl,--whole-archive ${MY_LIBRARY} -Wl,--no-whole-archive)`.

This works most of the time, but at some point the linker command will be like this:

`/usr/bin/c++  -g   CMakeFiles/my_exe.dir/my_exe.cpp.o  -o my_exe libmy_other_lib.a -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive`

This is rather useless, as the library is added beforehand and then the `-Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive` occurs.

Note, that I need to add something like `-Wl,--no-whole-archive` after linking *my_other_lib.a* because I do not want to use this option for external dependencies.

Any thoughs on this?

Comment: looks like a bug. When I read the docs on this it claimed that library names beginning with `-` would have their relative ordering preserved.
Another thought - is some other dependency target pulling in the same library before you get this far?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing these flags as a single argument to `target_link_libraries`, and not as a list:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} "-Wl,--whole-archive ${MY_LIBRARY} -Wl,--no-whole-archive")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the dependency now seems to be completely gone. Maybe I have to mention that `${MY_LIBRARY}` is a target and not a path to a file - so I guess it needs to be resolved.